# Why wont this move effect work on my sprites when the fade effect does?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, animation, sprite, move

Could someone please explain why this doesn't want to work? It's a bit of decoration to go behind a logo.

When the dMove var is commented out I get the appropriate line of squares fading in and out at random spots along the x = 78 axis, but when introduced nothing appears at all...

```
private var floatBG:UIComponent = new UIComponent();

private function addDP(event:TimerEvent):void{  

            var dY:Number = 5+Math.ceil(Math.random()*60);
            var dSize:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*12);
            var dAlpha:Number = Math.random()*0.5 + 0.2
            var dDuration:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*5000) + 1000;

            var d:Sprite = new Sprite();
            d.graphics.beginFill(0x1C75BC,dAlpha);
            d.graphics.drawRect(78, dY, dSize,dSize);
            d.graphics.endFill();

            floatBG.addChild(d);

            var dMove:Move = new Move(d);
            dMove.xBy = 300;
            dMove.duration = dDuration;

            dMove.play();

            var dFade:Fade = new Fade(d);
            dFade.alphaFrom = 1;
            dFade.alphaTo = 0;
            dFade.duration = dDuration;

            dFade.play();

            this.addElement(floatBG);

        }
```

Also, what would be the best/correct method for destroying the sprites at the end of each cycle?

Thanks a lot in advance, massively appreciate it!

Josh

Comment: I would presume then that the problem is in the Move class. Can you post that too?

Comment: @shortstick: Move is a Flex framework class, not a custom one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after a bit of playing around with it I managed to find a solution, I really appreciated Brian Bishop's help, who managed to very much point me in the right direction.

As Brian suggested, simply entering `d` as a UIComponent rather a `sprite` allowed the `dMove` to effect (I'm still not sure why this is, as the `dFade` effect worked when it was still a sprite). However adding the `floatBG` (BG being background, the UIComponent to which all the d UIComponents are added) each time was unnecessary, so I made `this.addElement(floatBG)` part of my `creationComplete` function

I then ran into the issue that the application began to fill with the d instances (d originally stood for "datapoint" by the way, which was kind of the theme of the effect which I was trying to create, a plume of them), and progressively slowed the application to a crawl. To continuously add d elements is necessary as it's part of the logo that sits in the corner of the screen looking as pretty as I can make it...

Eventually I came to the below solution, the crux of it was to load `floatBG` with 600 dummy UIComponents, and then with each cycle of the `addDP` function both add a moving `d` UIComponent to `floatBG` and remove another UIComponent off of the total array of children which it contains.

Thus, in the end it looked something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="init(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.core.DesignLayer;
        import mx.core.UIComponent;
        import mx.effects.effectClasses.MoveInstance;
        import mx.events.EffectEvent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.states.RemoveChild;

        import spark.effects.AnimateColor;
        import spark.effects.AnimateFilter;
        import spark.effects.Fade;
        import spark.effects.Move;
        import spark.effects.Rotate;
        import spark.effects.easing.Sine;

        private var floatBG:UIComponent = new UIComponent;

        private var floatColour:uint = 0x1C75BC

        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {   

            //Float BackGround set up
            floatBG.mask = floatMaskBlock;
            floatBG.depth = -1;

            this.addElement(floatBG);


            //Fill FloatBG with 600 filler elements
                for(var i:int=0; i<600; i++)
                {
                    var filler:UIComponent = new UIComponent;
                    floatBG.addChild(filler);
                }
            //Float Animation Timer

            var floatTimer:Timer = new Timer(1,0);
            floatTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,DPstartup)
            floatTimer.start();

        private function DPstartup(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            this.addDP(5,60)
            this.addDP(22,14);
            this.addDP(18,18);
        }

        private function addDP(yf:Number,yt:Number):void
        {   
            this.title.text = floatBG.numChildren.toString();

            var dY:Number = yf+Math.ceil(Math.random()*yt);
            var dXby:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000 + 50);
            var dSize:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*12);
            var dAlpha:Number = Math.random()*0.5 + 0.2
            var dMotionDuration:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*15000) + 1000;
            var dFadeDuration:Number = Math.random()*dMotionDuration;

            var d:UIComponent = new UIComponent;

            d.graphics.beginFill(floatColour,dAlpha);
            d.graphics.drawRect(78, dY, dSize,dSize);
            d.graphics.endFill();

            var dMove:Move = new Move(d);
            dMove.xBy = dXby;
            dMove.duration = dMotionDuration;
            dMove.easer = Linear;

            dMove.play();

            var dFade:Fade = new Fade(d);
            dFade.alphaFrom = dAlpha;
            dFade.alphaTo = 0;
            dFade.duration = dFadeDuration;

            dFade.play();

            floatBG.addChild(d);
            floatBG.removeChildAt(0);
        };
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>       
    <s:Sine id="Sine"/>
    <s:Bounce id="Bounce"/>
    <s:Linear id="Linear"/>     
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Group x="88" width="1000" height="80" id="floatMaskBlock">
    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xffffff"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Group></s:Group>
```

Ok, apologies if that was pretty long-winded, but someone may find it useful... it's a nice effect (I think so anyway)

I use the mask to give a sharp edge to the point at which the d elements appear. Alternatively one could just place it behind another object, but if, as in my case, the object is a line of width less than the size of some of the d elements, such a mask is necessary.

The colour is declared as a variable at the beginning as I'll likely add a function to change it on click, or something similar.

Thanks!

Josh

Comment: Was looking for a way to find memory leaks, used ver of this code as an example. Posted the question with details here (also includes very efficient fix for the memory problem): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958795/flash-builder-4-profiler-how-to-spot-what-objects-are-causing-a-known-memory-inc

Answer (score 1):

I ran this in Flex 4, only change I made was to use a UIComponent instead of a spirte, which works fine. Maybe your using pure AS3 project though? Not sure about destroying after they play.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import mx.effects.Fade;
            import mx.effects.Move;

            private var floatBG:UIComponent = new UIComponent();

            private function addDP(event:TimerEvent):void{  

                var dY:Number = 5+Math.ceil(Math.random()*60);
                var dSize:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*12);
                var dAlpha:Number = Math.random()*0.5 + 0.2
                var dDuration:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*5000) + 1000;

                var d:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
                d.graphics.beginFill(0x1C75BC,dAlpha);
                d.graphics.drawRect(78, dY, dSize,dSize);
                d.graphics.endFill();


                floatBG.addChild(d);

                var dMove:Move = new Move(d);
                dMove.xBy = 300;
                dMove.duration = dDuration;

                dMove.play(); 

                var dFade:Fade = new Fade(d);
                dFade.alphaFrom = 1;
                dFade.alphaTo = 0;
                dFade.duration = dDuration;

                dFade.play();

                this.addElement(floatBG);

            }

            private function onClick():void{
                var t:Timer = new Timer(100, 10);
                t.start();
                t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addDP);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button click="onClick()" />
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot. How should the elements be removed once they've reacher their alpha = 0 state?

Comment: Because floatBG is a private var, only copies of it are added to the stage, which remove themselves (im pretty certain). If you do a 'trace(this.numElements.toString());' after this.addElement in my example, and debug it, the result is only ever 2 (a button and a floatBG). Very small footprint. Will think on how to remove it. Good effect by the way, I learned from it, thanks.

Comment: I found a reasonable solution in the end to the accumulation issue, (below if you're interested). Yea I quite like the effect actually, gives a interesting pseudo-3d feel.

Comment: No I don't have a blog at the moment, although I have recently registered my name as a domain and is something I'm considering (I'm just not sure id I'd use it enough).

I'm hoping to get the site I'm working on at the moment up within a couple of months, summer at the latest, so if I don't get stuck into anything else straight away I may well give it a go!