# flash builder - tool for monitoring memory

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Does Flash Builder have any tool for detailed memory monitoring?

When my program is run for a long time it gets slower, and I would like to identify the problem.

When I press ctrl-alt-del to check my program memory it is increasing, but I am not able find which part of program is responsible for this increase.

Thanks for your help,

pavel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a profiler included with Flash Builder Premium

[Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0169-8000.html)

Answer (score 3):

Youve almost definitly got a memory leak problem.

I had a very similar problem, and was given some great advice. Documented all the steps involved in the memory profiling and in resolving the issue (with running example) - see the StackOverflow link below.

Hope it helps

[Flash Builder 4 Profiler: how to spot what objects are causing a known memory increase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958795/flash-builder-4-profiler-how-to-spot-what-objects-are-causing-a-known-memory-inc)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pro-filer is the best tool to optimize the memory performance.. it is inbuilt with flex builder but need to install flash player(Debugger version must).